# Fast way to compare arrays using two identifyer (rowIndex, colIndex)

Tags: java, arrays, comparison

Hello I'm working on a 2d map loader that uses chunks.

I'm using this method to calculate the positions of the chunk that are intersecting with the screen bounds.

```
// left bottom
rect.x = x - x % chunkSize;
if (x < 0) rect.x -= chunkSize
rect.colIndex = (int) (rect.x / chunkSize);

rect.y = y - y % chunkSize;
if (y < 0) rect.y -= chunkSize;
rect.rowIndex = (int) (rect.y / chunkSize);

// right top
float x2 = x + width, y2 = y + height;

float rectX = x2 - x2 % chunkSize;
if (x2 < 0) rectX -= chunkSize;
int colIndex = (int) (rectX / chunkSize);

float rectY = y2 - y2 % chunkSize;
if (y2 < 0) rectY -= chunkSize;
int rowIndex = (int) (rectY / chunkSize);

rect.rows = rowIndex - rect.rowIndex + 1;
rect.cols = colIndex - rect.colIndex + 1;

for (int i = 0; i < rect.rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < rect.cols; j++) {
        Chunk chunk = chunkPool.obtain();
        chunk.x = rect.x + chunkSize * j;
        chunk.y = rect.y + chunkSize * i;
        chunk.rowIndex = rect.rowIndex + i;
        chunk.colIndex = rect.colIndex + j;
    }
}
```

**Info:**

- If an Chunk is added it has to load data, if its removed the chunk data hast to be unloaded.
- This method gets called each time when the screen `x / y / size` does change.

**My question is:** I need to know what Chunks is removed / added from the last array. How can I do that. For identifying I would use the `rowIndex / colIndex`. It should be fast because it will be called frequently. Could a HashTable be an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hashtable only gives you one key for lookup, you need to lookup values by row and column. So you need to either create a composite key or use a table-like data structure to get the 2 dimensions you need. It just so happens that Guava has already implemented this here: https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#table

Comment: Do you know if negative index values are allowed?

Comment: yes any index is valid as long as it conforms to the type of your index key